# GatewayAutoConfiguration required a bean of type org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer that could not be found

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, microservices, api-gateway

> I want to setup communication between all the services that I created.
> When I add cloud config server gradle dependency in my project and run
> the project I got this type of issue

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method modifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory in org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

> I have defined everything properly according to my knowledge, But I am not
> able to find the issue from the last 2 days .I try myself
> these are the files I created in this project
> build.gradle.kts

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.4.5"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.32"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.4.32"
}

group = "com.main"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

extra["springCloudVersion"] = "2020.0.2"

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}")
    }
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

> ApiGatewayApplication.kt

```
package com.main.apigateway

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
class ApigatewayApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<ApigatewayApplication>(*args)
}
```

> application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8999

spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: DEPARTMENT-SERVICE
          uri: lb://DEPARTMENT-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/departments/**
        - id: USER-REGISTRATION
          uri: lb://USER-REGISTRATION
          predicates:
            - Path=/users/**
```

> bootsrap.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      uri: http://localhost:9296
```